# How can I compare all elements in an array with each other in liquid

Tags: arrays, liquid

How can below logic implemented in liquid template

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
for (int k = i + 1; k < a.length; k++) {
if (a[i] != a[k])
```

How can we do same comparison in liquid template.
{%- for healthfund in encounter.HealthFunds-%} have to compare a variable witin each healthfund instance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this..

```
{% for i in (1..4) %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
    {% assign value = i %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if i > value %}
        {% assign value = i %}
    {% endif %}
{%endfor%}

{{ value }}
```